# JavaScript forEach loop - trouble with specific element

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to loop through some elements with an attribute and based on which element I click, I'd like the `is-active` class to be added to the specific element.

The top section works, clicking on the specific tab, but the problem is with `tabBody`.

Right now, it adds the class to ALL elements and I cannot figure out where to put `this` to reference the correct `div`.

I just want whichever `tab-body` is active, to be the same `tabs-bg` is active, and have all that based on which tab is clicked.

I have this code (I've tried `let el = this`, says already defined):

```js
const tab = document.querySelectorAll('[data-tabs-tab]');
const tabBody = document.querySelectorAll('[data-tabs-body]');

function changeMe() {
  const activeTab = this.hasAttribute('data-tabs-tab');

  [...tab].forEach(el => {
    if (this !== el) {
      el.classList.remove('is-active');
    }
  });
  this.classList.add('is-active');

  [...tabBody].forEach(el => {
    if (el.hasAttribute('data-tabs-body') == activeTab) {
      if (el.classList.contains('tabs-bg')) {
        el.classList.add('is-active');
      }
    } else {
      el.classList.remove('is-active');
    }
  });
}
tab.forEach(el => el.addEventListener('click', changeMe));
```

```html
<div class="tabs" data-tabs>
  <nav>
    <ul class="tabs__tabs">
      <li data-tabs-tab="one" class="is-active"></li>
      <li data-tabs-tab="two"></li>
      <li data-tabs-tab="three"></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <div class="tabs__content">
    <div data-tabs-body="one" class="tab-body is-active"></div>
    <div data-tabs-body="two" class="tab-body"></div>
    <div data-tabs-body="three" class="tab-body"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="tabs__bg">
  <div data-tabs-body="one" class="tabs-bg is-active"></div>
  <div data-tabs-body="two" class="tabs-bg"></div>
  <div data-tabs-body="three" class="tabs-bg"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your snippet is not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.hasAttribute()` just checks to see if the attribute exists on the element.  You should be using `.getAttribute()` instead to get the value of the attribute.

Also, not sure why the `if (el.classList.contains('tabs-bg'))` block was in there, but I commented it out to make the demo work.

```js
const tab = document.querySelectorAll('[data-tabs-tab]');
const tabBody = document.querySelectorAll('[data-tabs-body]');

function changeMe() {
  const activeTab = this.getAttribute('data-tabs-tab'); // Change here

  [...tab].forEach(el => {
    if (this !== el) {
      el.classList.remove('is-active');
    }
  });
  this.classList.add('is-active');

  [...tabBody].forEach(el => {
    if (el.getAttribute('data-tabs-body') === activeTab) { // and here
      //if (el.classList.contains('tabs-bg')) {
        el.classList.add('is-active');
      //}
    } else {
      el.classList.remove('is-active');
    }
  });
}
tab.forEach(el => el.addEventListener('click', changeMe));
```

```css
.is-active {color: red;}
```

```html
<div class="tabs" data-tabs>
  <nav>
    <ul class="tabs__tabs">
      <li data-tabs-tab="one" class="is-active">Tab 1</li>
      <li data-tabs-tab="two">Tab 2</li>
      <li data-tabs-tab="three">Tab 3</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <div class="tabs__content">
    <div data-tabs-body="one" class="tab-body is-active">Tab Body Content 1</div>
    <div data-tabs-body="two" class="tab-body">Tab Body Content 2</div>
    <div data-tabs-body="three" class="tab-body">Tab Body Content 3</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="tabs__bg">
  <div data-tabs-body="one" class="tabs-bg is-active">Tab Body BG 1</div>
  <div data-tabs-body="two" class="tabs-bg">Tab Body BG 2</div>
  <div data-tabs-body="three" class="tabs-bg">Tab Body BG 3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Joseph! It's working perfectly now :) and thanks for the hasAttribute vs. getAttribute tip!

Comment: @fencepencil just a side note: you can use `Array.prototype.forEach.call(tab, (el) => {})` and bypass creating a new array on each `changeMe()` call.